# How to remove bottom border in android action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been found in forum, how remove the border bottom in Android action bar, but no method `(setElevation(0) and <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>)` work with my example.

Always have a border.

[image]

Thanks.

**RESOLVED:**

I did it!! Sorry, I was confusing because I thought the border/shadow was of ActionBar theme, but no, It was of Activity theme. I did it with "@null" added in style of the activity Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove elevation/shadow on `ActionBar` by below codes :

**By xml :**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            ...
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**By Java :**

To remove elevation using java code use only one below line... `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`

or,

```
 getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
 getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: Doesn't work... :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Theme without ActionBar shadow (inherits main theme) -->
    <style name="MyNoActionBarShadowTheme" parent="MyAppTheme">
        <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Use this style in styles.xml file

Comment: Opponent already mentioned that **<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>** not working.

Comment: Doesn't work because show the next error with <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>: 

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowContentOverlay'.

Comment: @JMR try this given style programaticaly in activity `setTheme(R.style.MyNoActionBarShadowTheme);` add this line as first line of onCreate method